# current_user_can not working in wp_login action

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add tracking to my WordPress logins but the function `current_user_can()` does not work in the `wp_login` action. Here is my code:

```
function track_logins() 
{   
    error_log('tracking login');
    global $current_user,$wpdb;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $org_id = get_org_from_user ($user_id);
    if(current_user_can( "is_student" ))
    {
        error_log('its a student');
        $record = $wpdb->insert(TABLE_TRACK,array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'org_id' => $org_id,
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'type' => 'login'

            )
        );
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'track_logins');
```

It displays the first error log but not the second. It isn't going into the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code and might have a solution for you but first I'm going to make a few assumptions looking at your code.

**Assumptions**

1.) You want to check the role of a user and see if they have student assigned

2.) `get_org_from_user()` is a function somewhere in your code, if not remove it from my solution

4.) `TABLE_TRACK` table name is defined some where and the table matches inputs of insert

**Function Inputs**

1.) Username of user used to login with

```
$user_login
```

2.) A WP_User object (info about our logged in user) [Codex Ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/)

```
$user
```

**Solution**:

```
function track_logins($user_login, $user) 
{
  // declare database
  global $wpdb;

  //not sure what this is?
  $org_id = get_org_from_user ($user_id);

  //I'm assuming you want to check the user role and
  //check for user role
  foreach($user->roles as $role){
      //replace role with the role you assigned to your students
      if($role === 'administrator'){
          $wpdb->insert(TABLE_TRACK,array(
              'user_id' => $user->ID,
              'org_id' => $org_id,
              'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
              'type' => 'login'
              )
          );
      }
  }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'track_logins', 10, 2);
```

**wp_login Hook**

I added 10 and 2 to the end, there is a small note on wordpress codex about it, simply put sets the hook priority so we can get the WP_User object passed to our function
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login